# How to save tabhost tabs between destroy-create cycle

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-lifecycle

Application has a tabhost managed through TabActivity.
It has option to add tabs at runtime.

Say 5 tabs are added in runtime and different activities are shown.

When I rotate the screen the activity undergoes the cycle o destroy and create. 
I want to maintain the tabs added by user in runtime to be available during this cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to change your Manifest to say that you will handle the orientation change yourself.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

What this does is tell the system to not recreate the activity on orientation change. You can then override OnOrientationChanged to modify any configuration changes.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //put configuration changes here
}
```

You can also leave it out if you don't need any explicit changes.

For further reading: [Android Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)